# changing font size of material-ui buttons, and having the buttons scale?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I seem to be having an issue with changing the font sizes on Material-UI's (for React) RaisedButton and having the button itself scale properly with it.

```
<RaisedButton
label={<span className="buttonText">Log in Here</span>}
/>
```

CSS:

```
.buttonText {
    font-size: 63px;
}
```

The text size changes but the button itself doesn't scale with it. Does anyone know the proper solution to this? I want to button to scale with the text size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is Material-UI inlines all of the styles for their components, so if you try to override them with CSS selectors it doesn't usually work quite right. Instead, try overriding whatever inline styles you don't want using the `style` property directly on the component. It would look something like this:

`<RaisedButton style={{ fontSize: '63px' }} label='Log in Here' />`

And if it still doesn't look quite right, just inspect all the generated inline styles on that component and see what you'd like to change, then just add that to the `style` object as well.

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button

Comment: What if you want to write a dynamic media query that styles the button differently at various widths?  Wouldn't I need a css class or html selector for that?

Comment: This is an old answer and MUI has overhauled their styling system. Now you would use the `sx` prop and define responsive values like [this](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#responsive-values)

Answer (score 11):

Use the `labelStyle` prop to override the inline style for the element

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button

```
<RaisedButton
    label="Button" 
    labelStyle={{ fontSize: '63px'}}
/>
```

Comment: Did you mean labelSize or labelStyle?

Comment: @CJBrew labelStyle, thanks for the heads up. I've edited the original answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
<RaisedButton
   label="Label" 
   labelStyle={{ fontSize: 15 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be added with lineHeight as a style prop for even spacing:

```
<RaisedButton style={{ lineHeight: "100px" }} label="lineHeight in style" />
```

Here's a fiddle with all of the different solutions: https://jsfiddle.net/botbotdotdot/kfph5cc2/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes props to override the default css styles applied to every material-ui component. You can find out more in this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mu8-u7V7Z8s&feature=emb_logo

Answer (score -1):

Use font-size unit as `Percent (%)` or `em`. For e.g `font-size:12%`

Comment: i tried both of these and they dont seem to work. i noticed that the button will scale horizontally but not vertically

Comment: can you share the fiddle ?

Comment: tbh I dont know how to include Material-UI in a JSFiddle. it is essentially just a raised button with a span attached to the title that i've styled in an external css file

Comment: did some digging and it appears that changing the height of these actually breaks material design guidelines... which is likely why they arent set to scale with the font sizes in material-ui. looks like I should just keep the buttons/font small.