# How to increase material-ui icons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I am importing an icon from `material-ui` and using in my JSX code as

Full code:

```
import ArrowUp from 'material-ui-icons/KeyboardArrowUp'
<Button fab color="primary">
  <ArrowUp style={{fontSize: '200%'}} />
</Button>
```

Using fontSize I cannot increase its size.

What is the proper way to handle it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: font-size:150%;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing font size of material-ui buttons, and having the buttons scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209780/changing-font-size-of-material-ui-buttons-and-having-the-buttons-scale)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the label style of the button like below

```
import ArrowUp from 'material-ui-icons/KeyboardArrowUp'

<Button fab color="primary" labelStyle={{ fontSize: '200%' }}>
  <ArrowUp />
</Button>
```

Comment: I used `style` instead of `labelStyle` which is worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

Create class selector in icon component like this

```
<Button fab color="primary">
  <ArrowUp className="arrow-up" />
</Button>
```

then write CSS code and give your style as important like this

```
.arrow-up{
 font-size: 20px !important;
}
```