# Stepper label font size in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stepper

how to change stepper label font size in react JS?
which file needs to modify for changing stepper label font size in react js as i am using material UI library
I having step.js, stepper.js, steplabel.js files in material ui

Comment: Hello @Vaishnavi! Welcome to SO. Does your questionanswer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209780/changing-font-size-of-material-ui-buttons-and-having-the-buttons-scale

Comment: Actually i need the file where i can change stepper label font size in react

Comment: Make sure you tag your question with the appropriate language and frameworks; otherwise, few people will see the question. I added [tag:javascript] and [tag:reactjs] but don't know if there are others. Also take a look again at [ask]